# Como abrir janela para selecionar arquivo após apertar no botão de Submit?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou criando uma aplicação e preciso que o cliente envie em um `<form>` um arquivo para o servidor.

Na minha página HTML eu possuo dois botões, download e upload, e eu gostaria de fazer com que o cliente selecionasse o arquivo a ser enviado somente quando clicar no botão de upload. Exemplo:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].onsubmit = function() {
    // Pede para o usuário selecionar o arquivo e depois prossegue
    // com a requisição ao servidor.
}
```

```html
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileUploaded" hidden="true"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar arquivo"/>
</form>
```

A ideia é fazer a mesma coisa de enviar um vídeo para o youtube. Após clicar no botão, o usuário seleciona o arquivo e a página envia o formulário. Como posso fazer isso com JavaScript puro ?

Comment: Acredito que não seja possivel fazer isso sem php ou node js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para executar uma função ao selecionar um arquivo, basta utilizar o evento `onchange` que será executado somente quando o usuário trocar o nome do arquivo.

Para realizar uma requisição sem que o usuário aperte no botão `submit`, basta utilizar a função do formulário `requestSubmit` que enviará a requisição.

Veja este simples exemplo abaixo:

```js
const msg = document.getElementById("msg");
const file = document.getElementById("fileUploaded");

file.onchange = function() {
    msg.innerHTML = "Arquivo enviado.";
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileUploaded"/>
<div id="msg" style="padding-top: 30px; color: #f00;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira de você fazer isso seria inverter a sua lógica.
Carregue a página com o upload visível e como `required`

`<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileUploaded" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar arquivo"/>
</form>`

Você também pode carregar a página com o botão `submit` desabilitado e habilitá-lo caso seu input de `upload` esteja preenchido.

Não esqueça de validar o tipo e tamanho de arquivo no seu backend também.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
let form1 = document.getElementById("form1");

//No evento submit.
form1.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

  //Verifica se há algum arquivo selecionado.
  if (fileInput.value == "") {
    e.preventDefault(); //Cancela o evento.
    fileInput.click(); //Chama a janela de seleção de arquivo.
  }
});

//Após selecionar e dar ok 
fileInput.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  form1.requestSubmit(); // faz uma nova solicitação de envio de formulário.
});
```

```html
<form action="/upload" id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileUploaded" hidden="true" />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar arquivo" />
</form>
```

A lógica é simples ao invés de fazer a solicitação de envio de formulário diretamente no evento [`form1.submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit), faça com que a solicitação só seja feita após o evento [`fileInput.change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).

No evento `form1.submit` inicialmente faça uma verificação para saber se `fileInput` possui algum arquivo selecionado lendo a sua propriedade [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-value) pois se nenhum arquivo ainda estiver selecionado, a string será vazia.

Caso haja algum arquivo selecionado `submit` prossegue normalmente upando o arquivo.

Caso não haja arquivo selecionado o evento `submit` é abortado via [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) e o evento `fileInput.click` então é disparado exibindo a janela de seleção de arquivos. Caso o usuário selecione um arquivo e clique ok, o evento `fileInput.change` será disparado refazendo o envio do formulário através do método [`requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit).

Comment: Ficou muito bom. Só achei a resposta um pouco confuso no início. Consegui entender melhor olhando o código.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002, e clarifiquei a resposta espero que tenha ficado do seu agrado.